# A subspace isomorphic to $C[0,\alpha^{\omega}]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\omega\leq \alpha<\omega_1$ ordinal, $Y$ Banach space, then $\ell_{\infty}^*\otimes_{\pi}Y$ has a subspace isomorphic to $C([0,\alpha^{\omega}])$? For me it would be nice if the answer was no.